# Starting an Activity on Condition

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I have three actvities. When I click on button they open with no problems,But when I want to open an activity by condition it is not working.

```
if(s2=="Both") {

   Intent i = new Intent();
   i.setClassName("com.gotit.babynames", "com.gotit.babynames.BabyNameActivity");
   startActivity(i);

   setTitle(s2);

} else if(s2=="Boys") {

    Intent j = new Intent();
    j.setClassName("com.gotit.babynames", "com.gotit.babynames.Boys");
    startActivity(j);

    setTitle(s2);

} else  {
    Intent k = new Intent();
    k.setClassName("com.gotit.babynames", "com.gotit.babynames.Girls");
    startActivity(k);

    setTitle(s2);
}
```

Comment: the last one opens... com.gotit.babynames.Girls..  if i remove and keep only setTitle if works perfectly

Comment: for some reason it is not opening com.gotit.babynames.BabyNameActivity or com.gotit.babynames.Boys .... the condition goes to else..        if i give like this it works    if(s2=="Both") {

       
            setTitle(s2);
               
           }else if(s2=="Boys") {

               
               setTitle(s2);
           }else  {
               
            setTitle(s2);
           }

Comment: setTitle is working ok but no Intent and startActivity code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using this:

```
if ( "Both".equals ( s2 ) )
{
    //Do something
}
```

`s2 == "Both"` will not compare the text in Java.

You can also use this to ignore casing:

```
if ( "Both".equalsIgnoreCase ( s2 ) ) 
{
     //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Even better:

```
// "Both".equals() will prevent NullPointerException
if ( "Both".equals ( s2 ) )
{
}
```

This way, you avoid a NullPointerException in the case that s2 is null

Answer (score 4):

In java, `==` compares the memory locations while the keyword `equals` actually compares both the strings. So, try `s2.equals` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can’t the use `==` operator to compare two strings. Instead of using `==`, use `equals()`.

Syntax:

```
s1.equals("xyz")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two Strings using == which is wrong. You have to use .equals

e.g.:

```
if ( s2.equals ( "Both" ) )
{
 /* Your action here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `==` compares the **memory locations**(references) while 'equals()' compares the **string contents** itself.

```
if( "Both".equals(s2)) {
    //Your logic Here
}
```